# Transfer vector space properties to dual space

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I am curious about this here (Actually, I don't know if my assumptions are true or not)
a)
Let $X$ be a Banach space that is isomorphic to $Y$, then $X^*$ is also isomorphic to $Y^*$.

I sketched a proof and basically what I showed was  that if $T\in L(X,Y)$ is an isomorphism, then also $T^* \in L(Y^*,X^*)$ is one which proves the statement.

Now I was wondering about the converse. It definitely holds, if $X,Y$ are reflexive, but does it hold more generally?

b) Let $U$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Then $U^*$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $X^*$. How can I prove this one?

If anything is unclear, please let know.

Comment: "No" to your first question. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647311/if-the-dual-spaces-are-isometrically-isomorphic-are-the-spaces-isomorphic) (the comments there also).

Comment: For the other question, it might help knowing that the dual of $U$ is the quotient $X^\star / U^\bot$, where $U^\bot$ is the space of linear functionals which annihilate $U$. HTH

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro is this a hint or an advice?

Comment: Neither of them. Actually, I don't even know if the thing that you are trying to prove is true. However, I am being told that the representation of the dual of a subspace as a quotient is a standard tool in functional analysis. That's why I am pointing it out.

Comment: I don't think b) is true. This is mentioned [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71118/subspaces-of-duals) on MO. I can't think of the relevant subspace $U$ at the moment.

Comment: thank you...this should answer my question anyhow ;-)