# isomorphisms of two vector spaces and their duals

Tags: linear-algebra

If two vector spaces are linearly isomorphic, then so are their duals. Is the converse true?
Thanks for your mention.

Comment: Are we talking algebraic or topological dual? In other words, does the dual contain *all* linear mapping $V \to K$, or only the continuous ones (for some topology on V)?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647311/if-the-dual-spaces-are-isometrically-isomorphic-are-the-spaces-isomorphic) may be of interest. Also, in the normed space setting, you might note the dual of a space and the dual of its completion are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: To fgp@ It is about algebraic dual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we're talking about algebraic duals, then the converse implication is at least *possibly* true, since it is implied by the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis, which is consistent with ZFC.

Under GCH, if the dimension of $V$ is $\aleph_\alpha$, then the dimension of its algebraic dual is $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. This means that if $V^*$ and $W^*$ are isomorphic (i.e. have the same dimension), then so are $V$ and $W$.

Now you may not believe in GCH, but this argument at least shows that you cannot hope to find an explicit counterexample (which ZFC proves is a counterexample).

Answer (score 1):

If a vector space is finitely generated it is isomorphic to it's dual space, so in this case the converse is true (you have a commuting square of isomorphisms).

I would venture to say that, if a vector space $V$ is not finitely generated, this might also be true, since for any basis of $V$ the dual basis spans the weak dual space of $V$ which is a subspace of $V$'s dual space. So certainly if two vector spaces' weak dual spaces are isomorphic, it should be true. I am just not sure if one can claim that a linear isomorphism would preserve weak dual spaces? The linear isomorphism will preserve the weak dual space as a subspace, but I'm not sure if it will actually be the weak dual space of the second vector space...maybe someone else can shed light on that. ok - I believe Henning Makholm has the correct answer for the infinite case.

Comment: What is a "weak dual space"?