# Predual: Denseness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Banach space $E$.

Regard a subspace:
$$\iota:U\hookrightarrow E:u\mapsto u$$

Consider the projection:
$$\pi:E'\twoheadrightarrow U':\psi\mapsto\psi\circ\iota$$

By Hahn-Banach find:
$$\varphi\in U'\implies \varphi_E\in E'$$

It is a surjection:
$$\pi[\varphi_E]=\varphi_E\circ\iota=\varphi$$

Also it is linear:
$$\pi[\psi+\psi']=\pi[\psi]+\pi[\psi']\quad\pi[\lambda\psi]=\lambda\pi[\psi]$$

> Then equivalence holds:
>   $$E'\cong U'\iff E=\overline{U}$$
>
> Especially one has then:
>   $$\|\pi[\psi]\|=\|\psi\circ\iota\|=\|\psi\|$$

How can I check this?

**Application**

Consider the Banach space $\ell^\infty$.

Regard the closed spaces:
$$\mathcal{c}_{(0)}=\overline{\mathcal{c}_{(0)}}<\ell^\infty$$

They have common duals:
$$(\ell^\infty)',\mathcal{c}',\mathcal{c}_0'\cong\ell^1$$

Identifications can't be canonical!

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647311/if-the-dual-spaces-are-isometrically-isomorphic-are-the-spaces-isomorphic) help?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Kind of, thanks!! Do you know a reference for its proof?

Comment: @DavidMitra: It didn't help directly but gave me new insights. Thanks!! *(See Application.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Special thanks to Simon B.*

By uniform extension:
$$\varphi\in U'\implies\overline{\varphi}\in\overline{U}'$$

This happens uniquely:
$$\overline{U}=E\implies\ker\pi=(0)$$

Especially one has then:
$$\|\pi[\overline{\varphi}]\|=\|\overline{\varphi}\circ\iota\|=\|\varphi\|=\|\overline{\varphi}\|$$

Conversely assume:
$$U=\overline{U}\neq E$$

By Riesz lemma:
$$\|\hat{x}_0\|=1:\quad\|\hat{x}_0+U\|\geq\frac12$$

This gives rise to:
$$\|u\|+\|\hat{x}_0\|\leq\|u+\hat{x}_0\|+2\|\hat{x}_0\|\leq5\|u+\hat{x}_0\|$$

Extend form distinctly:
$$\varphi\in U':\quad\varphi_\pm(u+\lambda\hat{x}_0):=\varphi(u)\pm\|\varphi\|\|\hat{x}_0\|\lambda$$

They are both bounded:
$$|\varphi_\pm(u+\lambda\hat{x}_0)|\leq|\varphi(u)|+\|\varphi\|\|\hat{x}_0\||\lambda|\\
\leq\|\varphi\|(\|u\|+\|\lambda\hat{x}_0\|)\leq5\|\varphi\|\cdot\|u+\lambda\hat{x}_0\|$$

Concluding the assertion.